# Mysql Query for Multiple table

Tags: mysql

I have two table question and answer. The structure is given below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `question` (`id`, `question`) VALUES
(1, 'Who is Mammotty'),
(2, 'Who Rahul Ghandi');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `q_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `answers` (`id`, `q_id`, `answer`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Actor', 'Y'),
(2, 1, 'Farmer', 'N'),
(3, 1, 'Engineer', 'N'),
(4, 1, 'Driver', 'N'),
(5, 2, 'Politician', 'Y'),
(6, 2, 'Teacher', 'N'),
(7, 2, 'Doctor', 'N'),
(8, 2, 'Pilot', 'N');
```

I want to display question and answer in this format

```
question         | ans1       | status1 | ans2   | status2 | ans3     | status3 | ans4   | status3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Who is Mammotty  | Actor      | Y       | Farmer | N       | Engineer | N       | Driver | N
Who Rahul Ghandi | Politician | Y       | Teacher| N       | Doctor   | N       | Pilot  | N
```

Can any one Help me ?

Comment: Do you know how many question/answer combinations you are going to have?

Comment: Dynamic, It contains N numbers of questions and each questions contain four answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each questions having exactly 4 answers the below query will help you. Same way you can include the status field.

SELECT qst.question, SUBSTRING_INDEX( group_concat( ans.answer ) , ',', 1 ) AS Ans1, SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( group_concat( ans.answer ) , ',', 2 ) , ',', -1 ) AS Ans2, SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( group_concat( ans.answer ) , ',', -2 ) , ',', 1 ) AS Ans3, SUBSTRING_INDEX( group_concat( ans.answer ) , ',', -1 ) AS Ans4
FROM `question` qst, answers ans
WHERE ans.q_id = qst.id
GROUP BY ans.q_id

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below query to get the result. i think this will work for you

SELECT qs.question,group_concat(an.answer) as myanswer FROM `answers` an,question qs WHERE qs.id=an.q_id group by an.q_id

Comment: Hi Vasanthan, Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this query will return all the answers with comma separated format. Not the format what I am currently looking for.